# How the memory of those object been released that is not been allocated?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4, memory-management, memory-leaks

I have initialize an image, like:

```
    NSString *url=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"url/%@",[self.urlOfImagesToDownload objectAtIndex:i]];
    UIImage *myImage=[[UIImage alloc] initWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString: url]]];
    NSLog(@"%d byte of data", [[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL: [NSURL URLWithString: url]] length]); 

    if (myImage)
    {
        NSString *jpegFilePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@.jpg",[self pathForDocumentDirectory],[self.idOfImagesToDownload objectAtIndex:i]];
        NSData *data1 = [NSData dataWithData:UIImageJPEGRepresentation(myImage, 1.0f)];//1.0f = 100% quality
        [data1 writeToFile:jpegFilePath atomically:YES];
    }
```

Now how can I release the memory of `NSString *jpegFilePath` and `NSData *data1`

And if I have a method:

```
    -(void) changeImageSlide{
     totalNoOfImages=[copyOf_myGlobleArrayOfImageIds count];
        if (imageCounter>=totalNoOfImages-1) {
            imageCounter=0;
        }
        NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.jpg",[copyOf_myGlobleArrayOfImageIds objectAtIndex:imageCounter]];
        NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
        NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
        NSString *fullImgNm=[documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithString:str]];
        //=(3*imageCounter+4)%25;
UIImage *img=[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:fullImgNm];
        [mainSlideShowImageView setImage:img];
        [mainSlideShowImageView setTag:[[copyOf_myGlobleArrayOfImageIds objectAtIndex:imageCounter] intValue]];     
        imageCounter++;

    }
```

It's been called with Timer(for implementing slide show), how can I release memory here in this one, from `UIImage *img` and `NSString *FullImageName`.

Along with that, how to be assured that once another image have loaded to  `imageView` previous image is been released from memory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither method needs memory released for the vars you mention because they use class methods which provide autoreleased instances.

but...

You will leak in method one for

`UIImage *myImage=[[UIImage alloc] initWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString: url]]];`

because there you init the object and thus take ownership. You need to release this at the end of the method

Answer (score 0):

Each of the objects you're asking about do not require you to explicitly release them as they are autoreleased. You can tell that they are autoreleased objects because the methods you set the objects with don't begin with “alloc”, “new”, “copy”, or “mutableCopy”. You also didn't retain any of them.

I recommend you read through the Memory Management Programming Guide. It will help you understand how to manage memory when developing for iOS.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/MemoryMgmt.html